# Moving WordPress site from localhost to a live server

Tags: wordpress

I have moved my WordPress website from my localhost server to a live server. I have the wp-config.php file well edited and have added to the home and SiteURL columns in the database the site url, but i still can't access my admin page on line and my site is still displaying error message (Error establishing a database connection)

Comment: Check your db user and password.

Comment: thanks, but they are all correctly written.

Answer (score 0):

Simple checklist for wordpress migration is:

- edit database table **wp-options** and options *siteurl* and *home* there
- edit **wp-config.php** (*DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD a DB_HOST*)
- use [this replace script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to replace all other occurences of absolute paths for relative path it is enough to replace your old site name http://yoursite.com with an "/"