# Wordpress redirection loop

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Where can I change manually the website url that is in Settings>General
in wordpress panel?

I have an issue.
I had one wordpress website in the url

```
79.170.40.53/theffashioneditor.com/test1/
```

and i wanted to transfer it to

```
tfeditor.com/test1/
```

So i packed the files from first domain server
and unpacked them to the second domain server
also did with the DB. Changed the wp-config.php with the new DB user pass and database.

Then when i tried to go to the "tfeditor.com/test1/"
it redirected me to the previous server.
I went to the previous wp admin panel and changed the HOME and URL to the new domain name "tfeditor.com"

and now im in a redirect loop whenever i want to go to tfeditor.com/test1/wp-admin it takes me to the previous domain with this path

```
http://79.170.40.53/theffashioneditor.com/test1/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tfeditor.com%2Ftest1%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

I login with my username and then it takes me to

```
http://79.170.40.53/theffashioneditor.com/test1/79.170.40.53/theffashioneditor.com/test1/wp-admin/
```

Someone can help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626876/moving-wordpress-site-from-localhost-to-a-live-server/33629132#33629132).
Simple checklist for wordpress migration is:

- edit database table **wp-options** and options *siteurl* and *home* there
- edit **wp-config.php** (*DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD a DB_HOST*)
- use [this replace script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to replace all other occurences of absolute paths for relative path, it is enough to replace your old site name http://yoursite.com with an "/"

Comment: You are completly right. Let me ask you one more question. When im on the previous wp site and i edit a page, it has on the link of the page "olddomain.com/page1"........ if i run the replace script it will change everything from olddomain.com to newdomain.com ??? And all of these links are stored in the DB??

Comment: Page links are built by wordpress and are not stored as absolute paths in database. But for example menu link could be absolute and there you need to do the replace. To be sure that wordpress regenerates page links correctly, go to Settings > Permalinks and just click save there. After correctly replacing wp-options values, running replace script (very important for media files for example) and saving permalinks, you can be sure that all links will work.