# Wordpress Site Broken after Changing URL

Tags: wordpress

I am currently working for a client who has hired other website designers in the past who have contributed but never finished the project. She wants a website at sheisbiddy.com but also had the domain name new.sheisbiddy.com which is the one that I began designing on. Last night I switched the URLs by deleted the site on the other name and change the URL on the new one. It worked fine until I tried to get into the site and a blank page came up saying "name ok". I googled a solution, which was to add the following code to my theme directory (I backed up first but it was after the domain switch):

```
<?php
update_option('siteurl','http://sheisbiddy.com');
update_option('home','http://shisbiddy.com');
?>
```

It worked and I got in a deleted the code by now my site is MESSED up. Pictures aren't showing up, the navigation had shifted and the magicline no longer shows up on the homepage, fonts have been reset, widgets stopped working... I checked my media library and some of the code and it seems to be fine so I don't know what happened or what I should do but I'm freaking out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626876/moving-wordpress-site-from-localhost-to-a-live-server/33629132#33629132).
Simple checklist for wordpress migration is:

- edit database table **wp-options** and options *siteurl* and *home* there
- edit **wp-config.php** (*DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD a DB_HOST*)
- use [this replace script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to replace all other occurences of absolute paths for relative path, it is enough to replace your old site name http://yoursite.com with an "/"
- also you want to regenerate static links, in Settings menu go to permalinks and just click on save

Comment: I did all of that and some things like the homepage background and a widget were restored but not nearly everything. Any more ideas/tips?

Comment: As you can see if you go to http://sheisbiddy.com there are two lines on the navigation instead of just the magicline, the whole navigation is shifted over,  and the background is white instead of black (i've tried changing it on the front end and backend and choosing a picture instead to no avail). I've managed to restore the rest.

Comment: other possibility is that you hardcoded links in the css, so open your css files and replace static calls with relative, or corrected static ones

also I checked your site, you have an issue with access control policy, because you are redirecting all calls to non-www domain, and your images are uploaded and saved on www domain, either change redirect or use replace to remove www from images links

Comment: Okay, I don't know what happened but everything is back! I think a widget was messing things up. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Thank you so much; I had a hard time finding a definitive guide out there for updating my domain on wordpress. This worked perfectly.